# Comparing two URLs

Tags: regex, perl

I need to compare two URLs in Perl.

URLs consisting of a DOMAIN only or DOMAIN/ (with the root URL ending with slash) are equivalent.

That said, the following strings should be count equal:
"http://example.com" and "http://example.com/".

Comment: @MichalKlouda — `http://example.com/foo/` and `http://example.com/foo` are not equivalent

Comment: could just check to see if index(a, b) + index(b, a) != -2

Comment: @M42 — What should he have tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[comparsion](http://lwp.interglacial.com/ch04_01.htm)

```
To compare two URLs, use the eq( ) method:    
if ($url_one->eq(url_two)) { ... }

For example:

use URI;
my $url_one = URI->new('http://www.example.com');
my $url_two = URI->new('http://www.example.com/');

if ($url_one->eq($url_two)) {
  print "The two URLs are equal.\n";
}
The two URLs are equal.
```

Comment: You should remove `$url_one->path('/');` since that explicitly sets the path of the first one to be equal to the path of the second one, instead of showing that they are the same if you just set the URIs with the previous two lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
my $url_1 = 'http://www.example.com';
my $url_2 = 'http://www.example.com/';

if ( $url_1 =~ m/\A$url_2\/\z/ || $url_2 =~ m/\A$url_1\/\z/ ) {
    print "URLs are the same\n";
}
```

Well given that they are really valid URLs. 
The regex only checks that if you add the "/" at the end, it's still the same URL

So if you add "/" at the end of $url_1, it will be 'http://www.example.com/' which will make the second condition in the if true.

Comment: Wrong: This would consider equal http://www.example.com/foo and http://www.example.com/foo/

Comment: I don't get it, you just gave 2 equal links there.

Comment: They are not equal. In a whatever reason, adding a slash does not change a URL only if the URL consists of the domain only. foo and foo/ are not equal.